# Which properties will be applied on hover event?

Tags: html, css

I am having two classes, each defining on hover event. If an element contains these two classes which properties will get applied to the element.

```
.classA:hover{
  transform: translateX(10px);
  color: white;
}

.classB:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```
<div class="classA classB"></div>
```

Would properites combine or override?

Comment: `color: red` and `transform` will work. But what stopped you from testing them yourself? :)

Comment: @m4n0 I want to know the rules.

Comment: CSS works from top to bottom. So of course the second selector with the same specificity - https://specifishity.com/ would override the first one.

Comment: Basically css precedence with order. The classname to the right of multiple class override the properties before it. Within the stylesheet, the class listed last takes higher priority over the classes before it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both the classes have same specificity, the class which is **defined** later will override conflicting styles.

Thus in your example:

```
.classA:hover{
  transform: translateX(10px);
  color: white;
}

.classB:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

`classB` is defined later so `color: red` will be applied and since `transform: translateX(10px)` is not conflicting it will also be applied.

**NOTE:**

Writing either `<div class="classA classB"></div>` or `<div class="classB classA"></div>` will yield the same result.

But if the class definitions were reversed:

```
.classB:hover{
  color: red;
}

.classA:hover{
  transform: translateX(10px);
  color: white;
}
```

Then `transform: translateX(10px)` and `color: white` will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer:**
Transform from `ClassA` and the red color from `ClassB` will be applied to the hover event of the element.

**Not so long answer:**
Since `ClassB` comes after `ClassA`, it will take priority over `ClassA`.
This is why the color from `ClassB` will override the color from `ClassA`. Since `ClassA` has a transform but `ClassB` does not the transform from `ClassA` gets applied to the hover event on the element. In case `ClassB` had a transform property too it will take priority and would override the transform in `ClassA`.

Hope you understand how it works now. :)